# Installing NVIDIA 361.45.11?

Tags: graphic-drivers

I have two monitor one of them is few older and needed the NVIDIA GeForce GT 610 graphics card driver.

Here is their [latest driver software](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/103306/en-us)

But when i try to install i get this error messages:

> [nvidia-installer.log](http://pastebin.com/pSZMwvgu)

How can i install this driver? or is it available via PPA?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

try to use the official PPA for the latest drivers of nvidia, you can see how to use it in this page
http://www.webupd8.org/2015/08/new-official-proprietary-gpu-drivers.html

but you should know that is a external PPA, so read very carefuli what are you doing

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to be aware that if you upgrade your graphics driver, you won't be able to run steam, in case you're wanting to upgrade it for gaming purposes. If this is the case, just check that you have the latest supported drivers in settings.

If however you are installing updated graphics driver for other reasons, [here](https://elementaryforums.com/index.php?threads/howto-install-latest-nvidia-driver-on-linux-without-getting-black-screen.7/) is a nice in depth tutorial on upgrading your graphics driver to the latest version. You should also be aware that once you've installed the latest version, there is no easy way back to the supported versions, so make sure you need it before doing it.

Comment: Hi, i installed nvidia driver, but while the os started to boot it shows the logo splashing but then afterwards black screen and nothing working..

Comment: This is generally due to not having set the following setting in the installation correctly: Would you like to run the nvidia-xconfig utility to automatically update your X Configuration file so set the NVIDIA X driver will be used when you restart X? You should have said no there. I would say boot into recovery, and try installing the driver again from the command line. Ensuring that you say no to that option. Alternatively you have errors in /var/log/syslog because you did not uninstall the nvidia-* packages from repository before installing the new driver. Uninstall them and reboot.

Comment: i have installed the nvidia driver from addition drivers tab!

Comment: Hmmm try [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/41681).